# cant create captcha using codeigniter captcha helper

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, captcha

I am using captcha and I want to create a captcha using the cpatcha helper! I read the user guide and write a piece of code, but it fails to create an captcha, so i use var_dump and it return bool(false), my code is as follows:

```
<?php
class test_captcha extends CI_Controller{
    public function main(){
        $this->load->helper('captcha');
        $this->load->helper('url');       
        $random=rand(1000, 2000);
        $vals=array(
            'word' => $random,
            'img_path' => './files/',
            'img_url' => base_url().'files/',
            'img_width' => 600,
            'img_height' => 400,
            'expiration' => 100,
            'word_length' => 4,
            'pool' => '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
            'img_id' => 'imgcaptcha',
            'font_size' => 18
        );
        $cap=create_captcha($vals);
        echo $cap['image'];
    }
}
```

the result is bool(false), so i try thses codes to check:

```
        if(is_dir($vals['img_path']) && is_readable($vals['img_path']) && is_writable($vals['img_path']) && extension_loaded('gd')){
            echo 'passed';
        }
```

return "passed".

**so could anyone help me with this?**

Comment: did you check if you have the GD image library installed?

Comment: yes i 've been checked, already installed and loaded

Answer (score 0):

Check your folder permission of your captcha folder. I chmod 667 the folder and the captcha object loaded and was able to echo the 'image' string.